# Automatic discount cross-sell product on Woocommerce Cart

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been thinking about the idea to make the total order value higher by giving the cross-sell product a discount on the cart page. These products are related, so giving them a discount would motivate people to also buy them. So I want to set a 10% discount on all the cross-sell products only on the cart page.

Tried a with a bit of php code but it doens't work. No error or anything, but the prices also don't change..

This is the design that i've had in mind. The 10% discount is there to bump up the total order value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZuzW.png)

The code i've created (but doens't work):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_cross_sell_discount' );
function add_cross_sell_discount() {
    // Lijst van product ID's waarvoor de korting geldt
    $product_ids = array( 10, 20, 30 ); // vervang met uw eigen product ID's
    
    // Controleer of de producten in de winkelwagen zitten
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $has_selected_products = false;
    foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $product_ids ) ) {
            $has_selected_products = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Voeg de korting toe als de geselecteerde producten in de winkelwagen zitten
    if ( $has_selected_products ) {
        $discount_percentage = 10;
        $discount_amount = WC()->cart->get_subtotal() * ( $discount_percentage / 100 );
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'Cross-sell korting', 'woocommerce' ), -$discount_amount );
        
        // Bijwerken van de winkelwagen met JavaScript
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery('.woocommerce-cart-form').submit();" );
    }
}
```

I want to set a 10% discount on all the cross-sell products on the cart page.

Tried a with a bit of php code but it doens't quite work.

This is the design that i've had in mind. The 10% discount is there to bump up the total order value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZuzW.png)

Comment: _"but it doens't quite work"_ is not a useful problem description. Please go read [ask].

Comment: @CBroe it doens't work. So looking for a code which does work

Comment: We are not here to find or write code snippets for you. The main purpose of this site is to try and help you fix problems with _your_ code that _you_ have written - but that requires a certain amount of cooperation from you to begin with, starting with a _proper_ problem description and analysis. (Like some basic initial debugging, which only you _can_ do, because you are the only one sitting in front of the whole thing, with the necessary access.)